# Spring boot + maven not printing logs on console

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

Running spring boot/java test project using maven through terminal is not printing logs.However when I run the project through Intellij(run configuration), it does print logs.

I have tried enable logging for spring boot by enabling logs in application.yml file but it didn't work. I have also observed that since intellij uses java to run the test project logging works however I am using maven from terminal so it doesn't work.

```
    logging:
      level:
        root: INFO
        org.package INFO
```

Enable logs in spring boot java project that prints stuff on terminal.

Comment: The `yaml` file's indentation doesn't look correct.. can you make sure it's just a formatting issue on SO and your actual `yaml` file is properly indented?

Comment: logging.pattern.console property should not be empty.

Answer (score 3):

Besides from the indentation, you are missing the:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.package: INFO
```

Also, you can configure the Logback for Spring-Boot, here is how to: [logback](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html)

Basically, creating a `logback.xml` file in the resources path, with the content of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

Here it is also another great tutorial: [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging)

Comment: true that. I am using surefire to run some test cases and seems like it was configured to reroute the logs to a file.

Comment: I could see custom application properties through `@DynamicPropertySource` annotation on a method which configures properties but it's not working for logging. I added `registry.add("logging.level.root", () -> "INFO");` but I don't see any logs in the intellij console